# Using Matlab's colon operator in OpenCV C++ without loop

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Are there any solution in c++ I can use like colon in Matlab.

in Matlab

```
image(i,j-one_count:j-1)=0;
```

Since I use Mat Structure Opencv, so it is also vector structure.

how can I write the same thing in C++ without using loop?

Whole code both Matlab and C++ in another question

[Attempt to implementation Running Length Smoothing Algorithm in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607017/attempt-to-implementation-running-length-smoothing-algorithm-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Considering the fact that you are using `cv::Mat`. Have you considered using [`colRange(int startcol, int endcol)`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-colrange)?

```
image.colRange( j-one_count - 1, j - 2 ) = 0;
```

Comment: I upload both Matlab and C++ related to this algorithm in this questin have a look

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607017/attempt-to-implementation-running-length-smoothing-algorithm-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Use Range function
you can use it as follows

```
image(Range(i,i+1),Range(j-one_count:j-1)) = Mat::zeros(1,j-one_count:j-1,image.type());

Range(a,b) can be used to get row/column from [a,b). ie from row/column a to row/column b-1
```

Also you cannot just assign the value 0 directly. you can assign zero matrix of equal size as the sub-matrix you taken from image.